# How to use @Qualifier with Service and Repository

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a generic repository interface called UserRepository.
I then have an interface which extends from that called MyUserRepository.
It deals with an MyUser class which extends User.

I also have a Service Interface called UserService and a class called MyUserServiceImpl.

The service wants an instance of the UserRepository and I though I could use some sort of annotation like @Qualifier but it doesn't work.

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface UserRepository <T extends User> extends JpaRepository<T, Long>{
    <S extends T> S findByLoginName(String loginName);

    <S extends T> S saveAndFlush(User user);
}

@Repository
@Qualifier("myUserRepository")
public interface MyUserRepository extends UserRepository<MyUser> {

}


public interface UserService {

    public List<User> getUsers();
}

@Service
public class MyUserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myUserRepository")
    private UserRepository<User> userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> getUsers() {
....
    }

}
```

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

> Parameter 0 of constructor in com....services.MyUserServiceImpl
>   required a bean of type 'com....repositories.UserRepository' that
>   could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>     - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

**Action:**

> Consider defining a bean of type 'com....repositories.UserRepository'
>   in your configuration.

Answer (score 2):

`@Qualifier` annotation is used only when calling a bean already created. So you shouldn't call on class head, you might name it `@Repository("myUserRepository")` and call it on after `@Autowired` `@Qualifier("myUserRepository")`

Comment: I tried changing the repo index to @Repository("mylUserRepository")
public interface MyUserRepository extends UserRepository<MyUser> {

} but that didn't seem to help.  BTW I tried changing the location of the Qualifier and Autowired tags from the property to the setter.  But you are right.  It seems to be looking for the bean before it is created (if it is being created)

Comment: Could the issue have something to do with the abstraction of the Repository class?

Comment: @GothsterC if you apply this answer, let me know if there is another issue or it is the same, if it is the same looks like you are working on a bean that has a referenced type, then it was not scanned , right?

Answer (score 0):

No need to have a qualifier in your case.

```
@Repository
public interface MyUserRepository extends UserRepository<MyUser> {

}
```

Auto-wire the repository as :

```
@Service
public class MyUserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository<User> userRepository;

    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

@Qualifier is used with @Autowired annotation. By default @Autowired will inject beans based on types.When you have multiple beans of same types then @Qualifier helps to resolve the conflict. In your case using annotation @Repository will do you job. Also in your UserRepository interface , you have to supply the Id class along with JPA entity class.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought I had you have to supply the Id class along with JPA entity class from my original code above.  Is there something wrong there?